# There are infinitely many primes $p \equiv1(q)$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $q$ be a prime number. Show that any prime divisor $p$  of $1+a+a^2+...+a^{q-1}$ satisfies $p \equiv1(q)$ or $p=q.$ Deduce that there are infinitely many primes $p\equiv1(q).$
The solution says: Notice that $$1+a+a^2+...+a^{q-1}=\frac{a^q-1}{a-1}, $$
if $a \neq1.$ Hence if $$1+a+a^2+...+a^{q-1}\equiv0(p),$$
then either $a^q\equiv1(p)$ and $a  \not\equiv1(p)$ or $a\equiv1(p).$ In
the former case $q|p-1,$ since $a$ has order $q$. Notice that any prime
divisor of $2^q-1$ is congruent to $1 \ (mod\  q).$ Thus, there is at least one prime congruent to $1 \ (mod\  q).$ If there are
only finitely many such primes, let us list them as $$p_1,p_2,...,p_k.$$ Then, putting $a=qp_1\cdots p_k,$ we find that any prime divisor $p$ of $$1+a+a^2+...+a^{q-1}$$ is first, coprime to $a=qp_1\cdots p_k,$ and second, must be congruent to  $1 \ (mod\  q)$ or equal to $q,$ which is a contradiction.

In this proof I do not understand  the part  "... and second...".Why  does $p=q$ follow ? If we take  a prime number $p$ that is not in the list and set $a=qp_1\cdots p_k+1,$ then we know $a\equiv1(p)$ leading to $p|qp_1\cdots p_k$. So we have $p=q.$

Comment: I don't understand your confusion.  No one is saying that the prime divisor $p$ must be $q$.  The first argument shows that any such $p$ must either be $q$ or $1\pmod q$ which leads to a contradiction for the specific choice of $a$ (which was based on the assumption that there were only finitely many such divisors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we know is that every prime divisor p of $1 + a + ... + a^{q-1}$  has to be congruent to $1 (mod q)$ or equal to q. Now if we let $a=qp_1...p_k$, then if the prime divisor is $q$, $a=qp_1...p_k$ and q have a common divisor. If the prime divisor is congruent to $1(mod q)$ it must be in $p_1 , ... , p_k$, since these were by assumption all prime numbers congruent to 1. In both cases $a$ and the primedivisor of $1 + a + ... + a^{q-1}$ have a common divisor, which cannot be true.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The prime number $q$ is  not one of the $p_i$

Comment: I never said it was.